# How do s3cmd and Tim Kay's aws script compare to one another, feature-wise?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

How do [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) and [Tim Kay's aws script](http://timkay.com/aws/) compare to one another, in terms of:

1. Feature richness ?
2. Ease of use and maintenance ?

Please tell me if this belongs to serverfault or somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Please also consider PowerShell command line interface which comes with CloduBerry Explorer freeware . This is windows only though

http://cloudberrylab.com/default.aspx?page=amazon-s3-powershell

Comment: Yes, I need this running on UNIX.